# Choosing observer points for Viewshed tool in ArcMap to identify visibility of landform

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, viewshed

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I want to create a polygon that shows all the areas within a region from which an observer could see a specific mountain.

I created a polygon around the mountain, and I'm going to create random points within the polygon to use for the observer points in the viewshed tool. The polygon is about 690 square kilometers, and I want to minimize the number of points I use for the viewshed so it doesn't crash my computer.

Is there a way to estimate how many observer points I should use based on the size of the landform polygon to get an accurate representation of visibility of the whole mountain?

Edit: I have to do this for a few features, including a single peak (one point on top should work), a basalt spire with a flat top (one point on top is insufficient), a ridgeline, and a small mountain range. For the ridgeline and small mountain range, maybe a point on each peak or high point would be enough?

Comment: That's a lot of words, can you simplify your question? As it stands your question is more likely to attract a chat than an actual answer which is frowned upon on this site.

Comment: As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking more concise and clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Wouldn't it work better the other way around? Put your observer(s) around the mountains. somewhere near the top and viewshed to locate where the mountain can see... if the mountain can see you then you can see the mountain. Create a viewshed for each significant mountain in your cluster then combine the results with cell statistics, lower scores can only see one mountain but higher scores can see multiple mountains.

Comment: One point on a top is enough, if you see it, you see a mountain, unless mountain has a crater or large flat top.